# Android In-app subscriptions purchaseStatus not changed after refund

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing, subscription

I'm trying to implement in-app subscription in my application. Everything seems to work ok, except for refund. I made a test account, and bought test subscription. In response got "purchaseState" : 0 (purchased). I immediately issued a refund through a Merchant Console, in response I got same "purchaseState" : 0.

Shouldn't I be notified of refund, so i can cancel subscription on my end? How do i handle refunds for subscriptions? I understand cancellations - state will be changed after expiration date. But refunds..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refunds are not supported for subscriptions. I recently implemented subscriptions in our Android app and had some of the same questions and saw the same results but confirmed that 'refund' state is never sent for a subscription. Mostly because Google does not give you a refund (unlike in-app billing).

Comment: So there is no way to cancel subscription in a middle? I shouldn't implement yearly subscriptions than =\

Comment: Sver, I've implemented subscriptions and the user can cancel the subscription in which case the purchaseStatus would be canceled and you'll be notified. However, what you'll need to do then is process the refund yourself and then not give access to the subscription data is purchaseStatus is canceled. Alternatively, what you can do (is what we do) is that you can simply put the warnings that there are no refunds for this data and you will get data until the subscription period ends.

Comment: @vkinra bro provide me some code for in-app purchase Subscription